# Dealers becoming synthetically short an out-of-the-money option

Tags: options, market-making, synthetic

> "When dealing with a large-size position, dealer, upon exercise, synthetically become short an out-of-the-money option."

How does this work, I cannot see why this happens synthetically in particular?

Comment: pls could you give us more context?  dealer is exercising an otc option?  listed option?  cash settled option?  physically settled option?  etc

Comment: FYI quote if from Page 27 of Dynamic Hedging by N. Taleb, I believe he is duscussing early exercise of American options ...

Comment: tks noob i posted an answer based on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one scenario:  dealer is long a deep in the money American put (say strike is K and the current stock price is S < K ), versus being short a european put with the same strike and final expiration.  If the dealer exercises early the American put, he is now short the European put at K with a short stock hedge against it.  Thus he is synthetically short a European call struck at K.  ("synthetically" via put-call parity).  I'm not sure if that's what is being referred to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the example of what is in the quote: dealer is long an ITM call. As a hedge the dealer is also short OTM put (with the same strike) and short stock. This is a "riskless" position, equivalent of a bond.

The underlying pays a dividend, and a day before the ex-date dealer exercises the call. The shares that dealer received from exercise are netted against his existing shorts to zeros, which leaves the dealer short an OTM put.